# Registry entry for Windows 7 title bar

Tags: windows, windows-registry, title-bar

I've taken a liking to the positioning of the Ubuntu titlebar buttons being on the left, and saw there is a program called Leftsider that does it on Windows 7.

However, I don't want to use a program to do that for me, and given that I'm confident with mucking around with the registry, I'd like to know where the reg entries for the Titlebar Button positions are.

Besides, doing it manually rather than automating the process gives me a chance to learn more about Windows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite sure there is no registry entry for that – Windows does not support UI customization other than what already exists in various control panels.

So various UI modification programs actually patch various Windows components (sometimes in memory, sometimes the actual `.dll`'s) to draw the UI in different ways.

In fact, the descriptions for Leftslider in various websites mention that

> *[...]* the program doesn’t touch your registry or system files *[...]*

More likely, it just modifies the window manager in memory.

Comment: most interesting...you'd think that a setting like that would've been included in the registry. Welp, I'm still all ears on any alternative methods that don't include Leftsider!

Comment: @Halodude: It was not included in registry because *it is not a setting* – Leftslider modifies the actual program that draws window borders.

Comment: welp, that clears things up. Guess I'll have to use LeftSider after all. Thanks for explaining it to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood what you want, this should be as easy as:

- Right-click the Taskbar at the bottom of the screen and uncheck the option "Lock the taskbar"
- Drag the Taskbar to the left of the screen
- Right-click the Taskbar (which is now on the left) and check the "Lock the taskbar" option

Comment: You are confusing the [taskbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_bar#Screenshots) and the [title bar](http://www.themebin.com/customizations/leftsider/)

Comment: @grawity - thanks, just re-read it and realise what the Op meant now.